# How to defend my base without PS+?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

It seems I can t actively defend my FOB without subscribing to PS+, so in case I am invaded, what happens? How can I mitigate this? Do I just trust my security team and develop weapons for them?

Alternatively, since I can t invade nor defend, is it possible for other to invade me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A person who has PS+ can invade your FOB even though you don't have PS+.

They have to face off against your security measures and guards. Since you can't actively join in when playing, you definitely must rely on the security measures and guards alone.

Yes it is possible to change up these tactics and improve your overall defense without having to actively intervene. You can do so from the Mother Base tab in the iDroid, under Security.

There are Basic options and Advanced options.

A good way to form your security is to consider the layout of the deck in question. Under basic, you can determine if you want your guards to be on alert and to what degree. The higher the alert, the faster they run around and actively try to find enemies and the higher the cost to GMP to run at this alert level. Under advanced, you can give them different types of guns between close, mid, and long range (those options only) as well as the number of guards, their stationed positions, security measures like cameras, lasers, drowns, and decoys.

With all these options, you should focus on keeping your security tight, if the deck has wide open areas, give them long range and position them together (same corner), if the deck has cramped spaces, give them mid or close range and spread them out.

Alas, eventually some rivals will infiltrate your base, there's never a perfect defense.

Comment: Are you basically saying that players who pay can grief other players?

Comment: @DeadMG What do you mean grief them? Making a FOB is optional to my knowledge, and even if you did make one per story progress, you are protected from multiple invasions and the loses are easy to make up with a mission or two. Abuse of FOB is pretty hard to do.

Comment: Probably obvious, but might be worth adding for anyone else looking for a similar answer that the same goes for Xbox Live Silver accounts.

Comment: But that does mean I can see some of my guy disapear because someone paying PS+ ended up in my FOB, also, the first one is difficult not to build.

Comment: @DrakaSAN yes, members of your security squad and a *small* percentage of resources are available for infiltrators to extract, if they are successful, these soldiers are removed from your motherbase and resources are removed from your resource list, when you sign on after invasion, you should be presented with a summary but this summary might not appear if you do not connect online, the summary can also be found in the FOB menu as the last tab  (not sure if you can access this one without PS+, I think you can).

Comment: So people NOT in the security team are safe from extraction?

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer "small percentage of resources" that's not true. I don't know how likely it is, but during one FOB invasion I lost 100% of my Fuel (which was about 10k or something)

Comment: @Maurycy that's worth looking into, perhaps there is a minimum cap as 10k is really not that much

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer True. Yesterday I was attacked and lost about 17.5k each of two different resources. Logically you can't steal more than is held on a platform, so the question to ask is - how much resources can be stored on a platform?

Comment: @Maurycy best course of action is to invade in FOB and record the amounts of resources you steal per each container and container type. I had a sweet run yesterday, I should have recorded it and posted the amounts, if I remember after work I'll do another run and try to record the extraction details (including what's printed by the FoxEngine on Screen at the moment of stealing)